# Cannot find Microsoft VS Lib

Tags: visual-studio, kinect

I'm rather new to Visual Studio and am trying to get Kinect running with it.

However, when I tried adding Kinect as a reference in my UWP project, I got an error saying

> The SDK "WindowsPreview.Kinect, Version=2.0" depends on the following
>   SDK(s) "Microsoft.VCLibs, version=12.0", which have not been added to
>   the project or were not found. Please ensure that you add these
>   dependencies to your project or you may experience runtime issues. You
>   can add dependencies to your project through the Reference Manager

I found something [slightly similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724378/could-not-find-sdk-microsoft-vclibs-version-14-0-on-windows-10) in stack overflow, the answer recommend installing UWP tools and repairing the Visual Studio. I tried those but it still didn't work. By the way, I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Commmunity Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one of the most common issues encountered when starting Kinect coding is getting the correct SDK, and that might possibly be what's happening here:

1. If you have the Kinect v1 for Windows or Xbox 360, install Kinect SDK 1.8
2. If you have the Kinect v2 for Windows or Xbox One, install Kinect SDK 2.0

I have found you can have both *installed* at the same time, but you cannot *load* both Kinect libraries at the same time - I think they both use **Kinect** as a namespace.

Second, last time I developed a new Kinect app, there was no UWP skeletal tracking. Not sure there were any UWP compatible features - I ended up using WPF. This could have changed recently but I don't think so.

If Unity is an option for you, I have found this to be an easy way to get started: https://vitruviuskinect.com/

Comment: Hiya, the framework I'm using the right one - Kinect SDK 2.0. But you're right, the kinect worked just fine when I use WPF. Thanks!